# Could not find module System.Console.MinTTY.Win32 when compiling test-framework with Stack on Windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm getting an error when attempting to compile Haskell tests using [test-framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework) on Windows.

## Steps to reproduce

Create a new library using Stack:

```
$ stack new repro simple-library
```

Then navigate into the `repro` directory and edit the `repro.cabal` file by adding `test-framework` to `build-depends`:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       test-framework
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Now attempt to compile the library:

```
$ stack build
```

## Expected outcome

The code compiles

## Actual outcome

Compilation fails with this error message:

```
$ stack build
WARNING: Ignoring mintty's bounds on Win32 (>=2.13.1); using Win32-2.6.2.1.
Reason: trusting snapshot over cabal file dependency information.
mintty        > configure
mintty        > Configuring mintty-0.1.3...
mintty        > build
mintty        > Preprocessing library for mintty-0.1.3..
mintty        > Building library for mintty-0.1.3..
mintty        > [1 of 1] Compiling System.Console.MinTTY
mintty        >
mintty        > src\System\Console\MinTTY.hs:31:1: error:
mintty        >     Could not find module `System.Console.MinTTY.Win32'
mintty        >     Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
mintty        >    |
mintty        > 31 | import qualified System.Console.MinTTY.Win32 as Win32 (isMinTTY, isMinTTYHandle)
mintty        >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mintty        >
Progress 1/5

--  While building package mintty-0.1.3 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How do I resolve this error?

## Environment

```
$ stack --version
Version 2.7.3, Git revision 7927a3aec32e2b2e5e4fb5be76d0d50eddcc197f x86_64 hpack-0.34.4
```

### Windows

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H1
Installed on    ‎14.‎09.‎2020
OS build    19043.1348
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume, given when you posted this question, you are using LTS 18.17. Looking at that LTS, it uses [mintty 0.1.3](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.17/package/mintty-0.1.3). Looking in mintty 0.1.3's cabal file shows a [special flag](https://github.com/RyanGlScott/mintty/blob/0.1.3/mintty.cabal#L51) that is enabled by default that means that `System.Console.MinTTY.Win32` is [not included](https://github.com/RyanGlScott/mintty/blob/0.1.3/mintty.cabal#L66). The comments in that cabal file say that that flag should be used when using Win32 2.13.1.0 or newer.

However, when I look at LTS 18's configuration in Stackage, I can see that it is using [Win32 2.6.2.1](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.17/package/Win32-2.6.2.1), so that flag ought to be set to false for this package to work.

So let's check that in the Stackage build constraints. I see that [another flag](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stackage/blob/lts18/build-constraints.yaml#L5280) is being set, and it seems to be an old flag that is no longer used (looks like it was used in an [older 0.1.2 version](https://github.com/RyanGlScott/mintty/blob/0.1.2/mintty.cabal#L47)). This must be the problem.

The solution: manually set the flag in your stack.yaml:

```yaml
flags:
  mintty:
    Win32-2-13-1: false
```

Comment: It seems this has been resolved in lts-18.21! https://github.com/commercialhaskell/lts-haskell/issues/329#issuecomment-1003883331